Synchronizing data between threads in C++ without copying or using std::mutex
I'm currently working on world management system for my multi threaded game engine in C++. The problem I'm facing right now is synchronizing world data between main and render thread.
The current structure of my world management is as follows:
Main thread (20hz):
WorldManager
└─ worlds
   └─ World
      └─ objects
         └─ Object
            ├─ id
            ├─ position
            ├─ rotation
            └─ Mesh
               └─ path to .obj

Render thread (160hz):
RenderableWorldManager
└─ renderableWorlds
   └─ RenderableWorld
      ├─ objects
      │  └─ RenderableObject
      │     ├─ id
      │     ├─ position
      │     ├─ rotation
      │     └─ Mesh
      │        └─ mesh data
      ├─ vertex buffer
      └─ index buffer

All the logic is stored in the main thread and all data used for rendering on the render thread. The object data can change every tick. My goal is to create world management system that is thread safe and stores parts of the data on main thread and render thread. My question is how to properly synchronize data between main and render thread without copying the World or using std::mutex?
I don't want to use std::mutex, because I'm using Vulkan for rendering so I need to manage my vertex and index data manually. The problem is that the std::mutex locks main thread until the render thread finishes updating the buffers, which ruins the whole purpose of multi threading.
My current approach is triple buffered request system. This approach has few major issues. std::swap isn't thread safe. I need to use std::shared_ptr so the request doesn't go out of scope. And I'm using World*, which isn't thread safe.
What is the best way to achieve my goal and how is this generally done in game industry?

You can use std::mutex in a more fine-grained way, surely?

"The problem is that the std::mutex locks main thread until the render thread finishes updating the buffers, which ruins the whole purpose of multi threading." The main thread would only be blocked if the main thread were trying to use the stuff being modified by the render thread at the same time. Also, why is the main thread modifying "vertex and index data"? How much information needs to be communicated to the render thread?

Main thread isn't modifying vertex data. Only the position, rotation, etc. The vertex and index data is created from mesh data, that is loaded (for now) on render thread. The data needs to be communicated to render thread when World is created, destroyed, or when object is created, modified or destroyed.

Difficult to know WTH you're talking about without any code. My comment above stands.

I'm not sure this will solve your entire problem, but one trick I like to use for giving two threads reasonably-thread-safe access to an object (where one thread is writing to the object and the other thread is reading from it) is to wrap the object inside a lock-free ring-buffer container, like this:
#include <atomic>

/** This class is useful as a safe, lock-free way to set a non-trivial value in
  * one thread and read that value from a different thread.
  *
  * It works by storing newly passed-in values to different locations, so that when the
  * value is updated by the writing-thread, it writes to a different memory location
  * than the one that the reading-thread might be in the middle of reading from.
  * That way, the reading-thread's "old" copy of the value is in no danger of being
  * modified while the reading-thread is in the middle of using it.
  *
  * @tparam T the type of object to allow atomic access to.
  * @tparam ATOMIC_BUFFER_SIZE the number of slots we should keep in our buffer to use for n-way buffering.
  *         Defaults to 8.  Must be a power of two.
  */
template<typename T, uint32_t ATOMIC_BUFFER_SIZE=8> class AtomicValue
{
public:
   /** Default constructor.  Our value will be default-initialized. */
   AtomicValue() : _readIndex(0), _writeIndex(0) {/* empty */}

   /** Explicit constructor.
     * @param val the initial value for our held value
     */
   AtomicValue(const T & val) : _readIndex(0), _writeIndex(0) {_buffer[_readIndex] = val;}

   /** Returns a copy of the current state of our held value */
   T GetValue() const {return _buffer[_readIndex];}

   /** Returns a read-only reference to the current state of our held value.
     * @note that this reference may not remain valid for long, so if you call this
     *       method, be sure to read any data you need from the reference quickly.
     */
   const T & GetValueRef() const {return _buffer[_readIndex];}

   /** Attempts to set our held value to a new value in a thread-safe fashion.
     * @param newValue the new value to set
     * @returns true on success, or false if we couldn't perform the set because our internal buffer-queue lost too many races in a row.
     */
   bool SetValue(const T & newValue)
   {
      uint32_t oldReadIndex = _readIndex;
      while(1)
      {
         const uint32_t newWriteIndex = (++_writeIndex & ATOMIC_BUFFER_MASK);
         if (newWriteIndex == oldReadIndex) return false;  // out of buffer space!

         _buffer[newWriteIndex] = newValue;

         const bool casSucceeded = _readIndex.compare_exchange_strong(oldReadIndex, newWriteIndex, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed);
         if (casSucceeded) break;
      }
      return true;
   }

private:
   static const uint32_t ATOMIC_BUFFER_MASK = ATOMIC_BUFFER_SIZE-1;

   std::atomic<uint32_t> _readIndex;   // cycles from 0 through (ATOMIC_BUFFER_SIZE-1)
   std::atomic<uint32_t> _writeIndex;  // increments continuously towards max uint32_t value, then rolls over to zero and repeats

   enum {TestPowerOfTwoValue = ATOMIC_BUFFER_SIZE && !(ATOMIC_BUFFER_SIZE&(ATOMIC_BUFFER_SIZE-1))};
   static_assert(TestPowerOfTwoValue, "AtomicValue template's ATOMIC_BUFFER_SIZE template-parameter must be a power of two");

   T _buffer[ATOMIC_BUFFER_SIZE];
};

You would need to decide where in your object-tree it is worthwhile to wrap objects with these; at one extreme, you could instantiate just a AtomicValue<World> and change nothing else, but the downside is that you'd be copying the entire world every time you needed to make a change.
At the other extreme, you could wrap every single object in the hierarchy inside its own separate AtomicValue<TheObjectType> and you'd be able to update any value in the hierarchy independently, but that might be too verbose and it could also mean that your reading thread sees "tearing" where some objects in the tree have been (safely) updated to the new state while others are still in the old state.  Whether tearing is a problem or not depends on the program's particular logic.
